# Bash turning multi-line string into single newline separated string

Tags: bash

How do I convert a file with newline delimited content into a single line like below?

```
blah
blah
```

into

```
blah\nblah
```

Comment: Do you want literal `\n` between lines?

Answer (score 0):

Or sed:
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/\n/g'
(credits to @kenorb from other question [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed))

Answer (score -1):

Multiple choices with output piped to sed:

**awk**:

```
awk 1 ORS='\\n' file | sed 's/..$//'
```

**Perl:**

```
perl -p -e 's/\n/\\n/' file | sed 's/..$//'
```

**sed**

There is also a way to do it in just in sed as was mentioned in other post. However, this:

```
sed ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g" file
```

May not work as `$!ba` might be expanded in some systems to the last shell command starting with `ba`. I would suggest other solution:

```
sed ':a;{N;s/\n/\\n/};ba' file
```

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that the only tag is the bash so if you want to use only the shell command:

```
IFS=$'\n'
last=$(<file wc -l)
cnt=0
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    cnt=$[$cnt +1] 
    if [ $cnt -eq $last ]
    then
        printf "%s" "$line"
    else
        printf "%s" "$line\\n"
    fi  
done < file
```